# Listview customization in Android different text colors

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a `ListView` which has an `ArrayAdapter` that gets its information from 
a String array. I have tried to used a custom adapter class where I had to override the `getView()` method in which I also used the `ViewHolder` pattern for what I am trying to accomplish. However, It was a nightmare since many views repeated themselves or didn't display at all and the rows were all scrambled.

My implementation of the `ListView` with its adapter is much shorter now.
However, what I want to accomplish is that some rows of the `ListView` will display text in red and others in white. the text that will display in red has the sub-string "R2". Remember that this text is stored in the String array that the adapter has a handle too. Well, here's my code, but am still unable to display the text that has a sub-string "R2" in red inside the `ListView`.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,main_instructions);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);

for(int k = 0 ; k < list_layout.getChildCount(); k++){
String s = main_instrutions[k];
if(s.contains("R2")){
TextView v = (TextView) listview.getChildAt(k);
s = s.replaceAll("R2","");
v.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
v.setTextColor(Color.RED);
v.setText(s);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listview.invalidate();
}
```

I think I have the right idea, but am unable to change those specific rows to 
red color text. If anyone has suggestions that would be great.

thanks

Comment: try doing that in the adapter

Comment: post ur adapter

Comment: You are calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after changing views color you should do that in Adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairy easy, for some reason I stopped using the `ListView` the momemt `RecyclerView` was released but the logic is fairy the same. If it were me I would first start by creating a

1.`data model` unlike having to make a `substring` its ugly and not recommended
A sample model would looking like

```
public class myModel{

private String myString;
private int viewColor;

public myModel(String myString, int viewColor)
{
 this.myString = myString;
 this.viewColor = viewColor;
}
....
}
```

2. Create `public static final int VIEW_COLOR_RED` and all other colors you wish to have
3. When initializing your model specifiy the viewtype e.g `list.add("this String", VIEW_COLOR_RED);`
4. In your listview adapter use this model you might want to google how to use a model than a string.
5. Am not sure about about a `listview` its been long since last i used it but in a `recyclerview` we have a method called `onBindViewHolder() which is in charge of inflating the adapter so you look for the method in your adapter where you inflate the view and do something like`

   `if(myModel.getViewType == VIEW_COLOR_RED)
   {
   txt_price.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.red);
   }`

its simple as that, good luck and I highly recommend switching to RecyclerView its easier if you ask me, incase you need the full code for the recyclerview and an adapter that switches textcolor comment below I have code that does exactly this.

Comment: am not using a computer, wrote the code from my head so it might not be work there and then

Comment: I just found out that the call to "listview.getChildCount() returns zero.. I don't know why.. if the listview has been initialized with an adapter. How can I access the child views of this listview?

Comment: are the adapters displaying?

Comment: what do you mean are the adapters displaying? The list view is showing on the phone screen, so I guess they must be displaying.